# EntityManager ThreadLocal pattern with JPA in JSE

Tags: hibernate, thread-safety, struts, entity, jpa-2.0

I'm developing a simple "Book Store" project using Struts 1.3 + JPA (with Hibernate as persistence provider). I cannot switch to Spring or any other more sophisticated development environment (e.g., Jboss) and I cannot use any Hibernate-specific technique (e.g., `Session` class).

Given the fact that I'm in a JSE Environment, I need to explicitly manage the whole EntityManager's lifecycle.

The `Book` entity is defined as follows:

```
@Entity
public class Book {

@Id private String isbn;
private String title;
private Date publishDate;

    // Getters and Setters
}
```

I defined three `Action` classes, which are responsible, respectively, of retrieving all book instances, retrieving a single book instance by its ISBN and merging a detached book into the DB.

In order to increase separation of concerns between business-logic code and data-access code, I introduced a simple `BookDAO` object, which is charge of executing CRUD operations. Ideally, all data-access related calls should be delegated to the persistence layer. For example, the `ListBookAction` is defined as follows:

```
public class ListBookAction extends Action {

    private BookDAO dao = new BookDAO();

    @Override
    public ActionForward execute(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form,
            HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws Exception {

        // Retrieve all the books
        List<Book> books = dao.findAll();

        // Save the result set
        request.setAttribute("books", books);

        // Forward to the view
        return mapping.findForward("booklist");
    }

}
```

The BookDAO object needs to access an `EntityManager` instance in order to do any operation. Given that `EntityManger` is not thread-safe, I introduced an helper class named `BookUnitSession` which encapsulates EntityManager within a `ThreadLocal` variable:

```
public class BookUnitSession {

    private static EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("BookStoreUnit");
    private static final ThreadLocal<EntityManager> tl = new ThreadLocal<EntityManager>();

    public static EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        EntityManager em = tl.get();

        if (em == null) {
            em = emf.createEntityManager();
            tl.set(em);
        }
        return em;
    }

}
```

Everything seems to work, but I still have some concerns. Namely:

1. Is this solution the best thing to do? which is the best practice in this case?
2. I still need to explictly close both the EntityManager and the EntityManagerFactory. How can I do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 26, accepted):

During the last few days I designed a possible solution. What I was trying to construct with the `BookUnitSession` class was actually the `EntityManagerHelper` class:

```
public class EntityManagerHelper {

    private static final EntityManagerFactory emf; 
    private static final ThreadLocal<EntityManager> threadLocal;

    static {
        emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("BookStoreUnit");      
        threadLocal = new ThreadLocal<EntityManager>();
    }

    public static EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        EntityManager em = threadLocal.get();

        if (em == null) {
            em = emf.createEntityManager();
            threadLocal.set(em);
        }
        return em;
    }

    public static void closeEntityManager() {
        EntityManager em = threadLocal.get();
        if (em != null) {
            em.close();
            threadLocal.set(null);
        }
    }

    public static void closeEntityManagerFactory() {
        emf.close();
    }

    public static void beginTransaction() {
        getEntityManager().getTransaction().begin();
    }

    public static void rollback() {
        getEntityManager().getTransaction().rollback();
    }

    public static void commit() {
        getEntityManager().getTransaction().commit();
    } 
}
```

Such a class ensures that each thread (i.e., each request) will get its own `EntityManager` instance. Consequently, each DAO object can obtain the correct `EntityManager` instance by calling `EntityManagerHelper.getEntityManager()`

According to the session-per-request pattern each request must open and close its own `EntityManager` instance, which will be in charge of encapsulating the required unit of work within a transaction. This can be done by means of an intercepting filter implemented as a `ServletFilter`:

```
public class EntityManagerInterceptor implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void destroy() {}

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig fc) throws ServletException {}

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res,
            FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

            try {
                EntityManagerHelper.beginTransaction();
                chain.doFilter(req, res);
                EntityManagerHelper.commit();
            } catch (RuntimeException e) {

                if ( EntityManagerHelper.getEntityManager() != null && EntityManagerHelper.getEntityManager().isOpen()) 
                    EntityManagerHelper.rollback();
                throw e;

            } finally {
                EntityManagerHelper.closeEntityManager();
            }
    }
}
```

This approach also allows the View (e.g., a JSP page) to fetch entity's fields even if they have been lazy initialized (Open Session in View pattern).
In a JSE environment the `EntityManagerFactory` needs to be explicitly closed when the servlet container is shutdown. This can be done by using a `ServletContextListener` object:

```
public class EntityManagerFactoryListener implements ServletContextListener {

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent e) {
        EntityManagerHelper.closeEntityManagerFactory();
    }

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent e) {}

}
```

The `web.xml` deployment descriptor:

```
<listener>
  <description>EntityManagerFactory Listener</description>
  <listener-class>package.EntityManagerFactoryListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<filter>
  <filter-name>interceptor</filter-name>
  <filter-class>package.EntityManagerInterceptor</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>interceptor</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm currently using Tomcat 7 and Struts 1.3 without any application server. Therefore, I'd say I'm not completely JEE compliant. From the view point of persistency, it is like being in a JSE environment. That's why I stated JSE in the title.

Comment: Hi, did this solution work out in the end? I heard about some issues with the ThreadLocal usage.

Comment: Hi, this worked out in the end, even if I had to apply some minor changes to the `EntityManagerInterceptor` class. To what issues are you referring?

Comment: burton0: I've had memleaks with ThreadLocal's (Tomcat gave me warnings); my solution was to add a @WebListener implementing the ServletRequestListener interface; and in the requestDestroyed() method do the cleanup i.e. threadLocal.remove().

Also, a favor. I'm currently in a Spring project, and I desperately need to get rid of Spring. Would you mind sharing the final version of your EntityManagerInterceptor? Perhaps in Google Code, or something? I'd really appreciate it. For non-Spring and non-EJB users, this is a very needed example. Thanks!

Comment: I implemented your method, but realized the code inside doFiler() was being executed several times per request. Is that intended?

Comment: Hi. Not really, the code should be executed once per request.

Comment: I mapped the filter to xhtml pages. I am using facelets and templating, including other pages before serving. Could that be the reason?

Comment: I'm not familiar with facelets. As a general principle, any single request will get bound to its own EntityManager. Hence, you should try to understand how many requests are triggered.

Answer (score 0):

[ScopedEntityManager](https://github.com/Murmur/ScopedEntityManager/blob/master/src/es/claro/persistence/ScopedServletListener.java) helper tool I have created in Github uses a similar technique. Instead of request filter I have chosen ServletRequestListener for lifecycle management. Also I am not using a threadlocal because they have a habit of memory leaks in J2EE containers if not programmed carefully. Tomcat do have some tricks to failsafe certain human errors.