# SessionFactory.getCurrentSession with EntityManager?

Tags: hibernate, session, jakarta-ee, jpa

I switched from using Hibernate API to the JPA API. Now im wondering because EntityMangager(Factory) does not feature any SessionFactory#getCurrentSession like  methods.

Is there any build in comparable approach with EntityManger?

Comment: Can you give an example what you would do with the session once you have it? You can probably accomplish everything with entity manager, I have never had the need to use session directly

Comment: Im using the sesson per request pattern, managing the sessions in a ServletFilter and accessed them with SessionFactory#getCurrentSession.

Answer (score -2):

You can get the session using `Session session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class)`, where `Session` is a `org.hibernate.Session`.

Comment: I´dont need an explicit Session I just need the "current Persistence Object" (=EntityManager) used in the http Request Scope (e.g. Threadlocal scope).
As described this was achieved by implementing the Session per Request pattern and using SessionFactory#getCurrentSession before moving to EntityManager

Comment: You could do that using `ThreadLocal`s, take a look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15159818/4074715) for more info